# How to kill/stop all bats from spawning?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm making a horror map in a cave system, I can't keep the bats from spawning!

Comment: Don't bats help with the horror aspect?

Comment: Not if they keep breeding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no command blocks on Xbox the only option you have is lighting up your cave. This may remove the so said "horror" effect but I don't think there is another way.

The light level needs to be higher then 4 in order to prevent them from spawning. Check [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bat) wiki page for more information.

Comment: Ah thanks man....maybe redstone torches will work...i can put them behind paintings

Answer (score 0):

Create some kind of clock with a command block on it, and put this command in it:

```
/kill @e[type=Bat]
```

This will kill all entities that are bats as soon as they spawn.

---

If you want to prevent all mobs from spawning, you could also just use:

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

This command does not need to be put on a clock, just run once.

Comment: Xbox 360 has no command blocks

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki Its probably a good idea if you add the xbox tag to the question.